# how use jdk for java projects in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java

I install jre and jdk, then install Eclipse, I want to create new java project and run it with jdk. For another program I need rename jkd on jskd, in tip JRE in eclipse I can't choose jsdk, how to change this?

Comment: you mean jkd -> jdk and jskd ->jsdk? what is "tip JRE"?

Comment: Eclipse require JDK for compilation.

Comment: No, Eclipse comes with its own Java Compiler.  It does require a JRE to run your Java application, as well as itself, and to have the libraries to compile against.

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to understand what you are asking but it you want to select a JDK in eclipse:

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add -> Check your JDK

Answer (score 0):

If you mean which JRE you want to use for your project, in eclipse this can be configured by going to the "project" menu > "properties" > "Java building path". In the "Java building path" you can define the "JRE system library".